# Django send push notification when database value changed

Tags: python, django, notifications

I'm newbie with Django, and I have to create a server that is able to detect when a specific value into the database is lesser than X, and then, send a notification to specific user.

My idea was something like:

1. Value lesser than X is detected.
2. The server adds a `notification` record to notification's table into database.
3. Server send a push notification to the designed user.

In the app there is a view for notifications that reads the mentioned table.

I'm able to implement points 2 and 3, but the first point I have no idea of how I can start it.

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with android/ios..  Anyway you can achieve it using a [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/) signal in django

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be achieved either by overriding save method or using post_save signal.

The first option could look like this:

```
class Foo(model.Model):
    # here you define your fields
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.desired_field < X:
            # logic goes here
```

The second option can be implemented this way:

```
class Foo(model.Model):
    # here you define your fields

@receiver(post_save, sender=Foo)
def notify(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.desired_field < X:
       # logic goes here
```

Comment: This can read when an update is made on my database, then evaluate if the value is lesser than X, as I'm understanding, right? Okey, i'm going to test it. Thanks for your response @mateuszb!

Comment: It works! Solution was very simple, that things make me love Django and Python. Dziękuję!